# Help proving a set equality - exercise from the book of proof third edition by Richard Hammack

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am going through The Book of Proof - Third Edition by Richard Hammack, and came across this exercise:
Do you think the statement $(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}=(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$ is true, or false? Justify.

I think the intent of the question was for me to answer graphically, since proving set equality was not introduced yet, but I attempted to do it anyway. Can someone offer a constructive feedback on my technique? Thanks in advance.

$\mathbf{Ans.}$ The statement is true.

Proof: Let $k\in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}$. Then, $k=(x_1,n_1):x_1\in\mathbb{R},x_1\notin\mathbb{Z},n_1\in\mathbb{N}$. This means $k\in(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})$ and $k\notin(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$. Thus $(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}\subseteq(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$.

Now, let $l\in(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$. Then, $l\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$ and $l\notin\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$. This means $l$ is of the form $(x_2,n_2):x_2\in\mathbb{R},x_2\notin\mathbb{Z},n_2\in\mathbb{N}$. Thefore, $l\in(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})\subseteq(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}$.

We conclude $(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z})\times\mathbb{N}=(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N})-(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N})$.

It feels to me I might have omitted some steps along the way, but I am not sure how to improve the proof further.

Comment: "The Book of Proof" -- who by?

Comment: Richard Hammack

Comment: Standard practice here is to edit the question to add that information to it, or so I believe.

Comment: Sorry, new here. Edited.

Answer (score -1):

I would go in a different approach, although your proof seems good, I wouldn't use "of the form", maybe "can be represented as", just a suggestion.
for my proof, I'm using the following statement:
$\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N} ~ \mathbb{R}$ which implies they have the same cardinality. if we can prove it, we are finished with our statement.
proof:
we will do it by building a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$
let $f$ be the function such that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}. $
$f$ is defined as the following:$ f(x) = \text{if x is even then}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \text{ else, }\rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}. $
here you only need to prove that it is well difined and that it is a bijection.
after you prove it, you know that they have the same cardinality and also that:$|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}| $ and so:$\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.We can conclude that this claim is correct, this is how I would approach it. hope it helps. we showed that the cardinality is the same hence we just need to look on one element and show that it is from the same form of the other.

Comment: After coming from another of your answers, checking what other posts you've made... this too is quite wrong.  You seem to have interpreted the question as asking about if sets have the same cardinality.  The question does not mention cardinality, does not use bars implying cardinality, or anything else of the sort.  The question is asking if the two sets are *equal as sets*, a much more restrictive question than simply asking if they are the same cardinality.  It is asking if every element of the first is also an element of the second and vice versa.